# Refresh/Update Calendar After Setting todaysdate with TextBox c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox, calendar

I have a Calendar and a TextBox (which represents the year).
I want to navigate the Calendar through the TextBox input.
For example write in the TextBox 1988 and go to that year in the Calendar.

Here is the code that supposed to update the Calendar to a new year.

birthday is the Calendar and year is the TextBox

```
protected void updateYear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iYear = Convert.ToInt32(year.Text);
    if (iYear > 1890 && iYear < DateTime.Today.Year - 18)
    {
        int month = birthday.TodaysDate.Month;
        int day = birthday.TodaysDate.Day;
        DateTime today = new DateTime(iYear, month, day);
        birthday.TodaysDate = today;
        birthday.SelectedDate = today;
    }
}
```

I need somehow to update/refresh the Calendar.

By the way the code works, it **goes** to the year **only after** I select a date on the Calendar, it refreshes the Calendar and goes to the specified year.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a Refrash() in the end

```
protected void updateYear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iYear = Convert.ToInt32(year.Text);
    if (iYear > 1890 && iYear < DateTime.Today.Year - 18)
    {
        int month = birthday.TodaysDate.Month;
        int day = birthday.TodaysDate.Day;
        DateTime today = new DateTime(iYear, month, day);
        birthday.TodaysDate = today;
        birthday.SelectedDate = today;
        birthday.Refresh();
    }
}
```

see the MSDN link [MonthCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and in any control that you change in the code it is recomended to refresh it after the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of the MonthCalendar class but I am using the Calendar


  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.aspx

 class which does not have a refresh method.

Comment: Gal can you please help me, I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: Hi, I am less familiar whit the web control I dont use them at my line of work I will guss that you are building a web page now or a web app of some kind so you have 2 option I think refresh the web page or use ajax to refresh only the control  you can try render() but I am not sure it will work                                                                                                             if you are not using a web application then please dont use web control but usual c# controls

Comment: Thanks Gal, I already found the answer, I had to set AutoPostBack="true" in the TextBox.